# if statement foreach slide count to have an active indicator?

Tags: jquery

im try to get for id slide-1  that has an attr of displays block then add a class to id pagecount-1 of active... im trying to get for each slide the indicator shown to be active    this is what i have :

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="sp active" id="slide-1" style="display: block"></div>
  <div class="sp" id="slide-2" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="sp" id="slide-3" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="sp" id="slide-4" style="display: none"></div>
</div>

<div id="page">
  <div id="page_count-1" class="indicate"></div>
  <div id="page_count-2" class="indicate"></div>
  <div id="page_count-3" class="indicate"></div>
  <div id="page_count-4" class="indicate"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code checks for all `slide` elements if they are visible and applies the `active` class to the corresponding `page_count` element:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if ($('#slide-' + i).is(':visible')) {
        $('#page_count-' + i).addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! now  do i just add that just as is to my custom scripts?? or do i need to wrap it in something

Comment: Put it in your document ready function ( `$(function() { ... });` )

Comment: There was a missing `)`, I fixed it.

Comment: its not adding the active class i actually have 11 slides so i changed it a little                                                      for (var i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
    if ($('#slider .sp#slide-' + i).is(':visible')) {
        $('.page #page_count-' + i).addClass('active');
    }
};

Comment: If an element has an id you don't need other classes or parent elements to select it: `$('#slider .sp#slide-' + i)` should be `$('#slide-' + i)`

Comment: instead of .is(':visible') can i use .attr('display', 'block') seems like visible is not working

Comment: with is visible its making ALL #page_counts active at once instead of each

Comment: if i run console log with .is:visible i get undefine

Comment: Have you tried `.is:visible` or `.is(':visible')`? The parentheses and quotes are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slider div').each(function() {
    var currentIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('slide-',''));
    if($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
        $("#page_count-" + currentIndex).addClass("active");  
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/bZj2B/